# How to sing SATB parts as a Baritone

Tags: voice, vocal-range, choir

Wikipedia lists [these guidelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_range) as typical ranges for different vocal types:

- Soprano: C4–C6
- Mezzo-soprano: A3–A5
- Contralto: F3–F5
- Countertenor: E3-E5
- Tenor: C3–C5
- Baritone: G2–G4
- Bass: E2-E4

My range is A2 - G4 which puts me as a cut & dried baritone; I can just reach G2 and as high as C5 but not reliably or with good tone.

Christmas is approaching and with it, carol singing. All the pieces we have are in standard [SATB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATB) format which leaves me struggling, especially as an inexperienced/untrained singer, not knowing what to do.

From the point of view of a singer, what would work best? Equally, what is helpful to the "choir master" and what should I *avoid* doing?

Answer (score 5):

It's simple. If you are a baritone, and the music is arranged in four parts, you sing the bass part. You might be a bit weak on the lowest notes, but hopefully there will be other bass singers in your section who can cover that part of the range. On the other hand the baritones sound good on the highest notes in the bass part which the true basses can't reach easily. It all averages out if you have just a few good basses and baritones in the bass section.

Enjoy your caroling. It's much more about getting into the spirit of the season than it is about having great singing technique. Just tell them you won't go until they bring you some figgy pudding. That's worked for centuries.

Comment: It absolutely should be fun, but as the one time of the year I sing from sheet music it's quite stressful. You think you know all these songs from childhood, then you have to sing parts and learn all the songs over!

Comment: I tell my guitar pupils that sight-singing is "musical-porridge". You might not like it, but it's really good for you...

Comment: Out of interest why do you view it as such an obvious choice to go bass rather than tenor? I think my range covers as much of the tenor range as the bass - maybe because it's more grating hearing a bad high note than a bad low note?

Comment: In choirs all over the world, baritones always sing in the bass section. It has always been this way. There is no exception to this. If you are put in the tenor section, then by definition you are singing tenor because you are a tenor. If you are put in the bass section, you may be either a baritone or a bass. That is what the bass section is for, and choral composers write their music in such a way that they want baritones and basses singing in the bass section.

Comment: Solo singing can be a bit different. There are exceptional baritones that can actually cover the entire tenor range as well as the traditional baritone range (in some operatic roles, for instance), but they are very rare. However, it's not only about the range of notes but also the tone or timbre of the voice. If your choir director recognizes you as a baritone, they will put you in the bass section. The music is written and arranged for your voice type to be singing the bass part.

Comment: Also note that when we say SATB, we mean four parts, but there may well be many places in a piece of music where one section is divided in half, a lower part and an upper part. Thus you might see a bass part with two lines of music on the same staff, in which case the baritones sing the upper line and the true basses sing the lower line. Similarly there is a distinction between 1st tenor (higher) and 2nd tenor (lower), 1st and 2nd alto, and true soprano and mezzo-soprano. So choral music sometimes is written in as many as eight parts.

Comment: Great information @WheatWilliams, thankyou. I'd better ascertain I really _am_ a baritone though it seems this is pretty much the case unless my ability to gauge my range is flawed! Your lengthy comments would be great moved verbatim into your answer btw...

Comment: Most choral music (and this is a good thing) is written somewhat simply so that amateur musicians can come together and sing it. It's inclusive. So lumping people into S, A, T, and B is kind of a gross over-simplification but it works well. Certain individuals who get a great deal of training might find out that they have a very wide range that can span from one section to the other. But you have to be born with that rare kind of voice. For instance, I'm highly-trained but I'm squarely in the 1st Tenor voice type. I don't even like to sing 2nd tenor -- I don't think I sound good there.

Comment: So follow the wishes of your choir director and work on those parts they assign you. I hope you'll find it fun and rewarding, and moreover that you will enjoy the company of the other singers. Choirs are about community.

Comment: Also, I envy baritones, because generally speaking they have the widest range of notes of all the male voice types. Tenors like me generally have the smallest range. There are certain women who can cover first soprano to first alto, and there are female altos who can sing first tenor. But for any given population of amateur singing enthusiasts in your local community center or church, assigning a person permanently to either S, A, T or B works well, and the music is written with this expectation.

Comment: In every large amateur choir, there are a few men in the bass section that call themselves baritones. But in fact they are natural tenors who never got singing lessons and never did the work to develop their upper range. There are similarly some women in the alto section who might be able to sing soprano if they got some training. But it's all good. Some singers want to spend a lot of time improving their singing, and some just want to participate in a fun part-time activity. Hopefully your choir will have some of both. That is as it should be.

Comment: If you take enough lessons and practice enough, you may well find out that you are better in the tenor range than in the baritone range. I have a friend who majored in vocal performance for four years as a baritone. After he graduated he continued to take private voice lessons and came to the conclusion that he was really a tenor all along. It's rare but it happens to some baritones. Anyway, singing is a journey and a community activity, so just have fun doing it!